# Nifi ConsumeKafkaRecord change heartbeat

Tags: apache-nifi

i have KafkaRecordConsumer_2_0 in nifi and i want to change it's heartbeat interval.
is there a way to do so?
i've read the documentation and the code and didn't find any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a dynamic property in your kafka consumer processor :
key: heartbeat.interval.ms
value: the new value

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-kafka-2-0-nar/1.9.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.kafka.pubsub.ConsumeKafka_2_0/index.html

> Dynamic Properties:
>
> Dynamic Properties allow the user to specify both the name and value
> of a property.
>
> Name: The name of a Kafka configuration property.
> Value: The value of a given Kafka configuration property.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Worked :-)